# Inequality with $\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+w}{(x+y+z)^3}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $x,y,z,w>0$ and $x+y+z+w=1$. What is the minimum value of
$$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+w}{(x+y+z)^3}+\frac{y^2+z^2+w^2+x}{(y+z+w)^3}+\frac{z^2+w^2+x^2+y}{(z+w+x)^3}+\frac{w^2+x^2+y^2+z}{(w+x+y)^3}?$$

When all variables are equal (to $0.25$), the value of the expression is $4\frac{4}{27}$. If we want to homogenize the numerator, we can do
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+w=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+wx+wy+wz.$$
Applying the AM-GM inequality then gives
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+w\geq \frac{2}{3}(xy+yz+zx)+\frac{5}{3}(wx+wy+wz).$$

Comment: This is a possible approach... clear the denominator using symmetrical sum notation, then cancel out terms and hopefully AM-GM or QM-AM will give you the answer.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Why do you want to close this topic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83101/discussion-between-thesimplifire-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right! The minimal value is $4\frac{4}{27}.$

Indeed, by the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{w}{x+y+z}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y+z+w}{x+y+z}-4=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}(x+y+z)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+y+z}-4\geq\frac{16}{3}-4=\frac{4}{3}.$$
That is, by Cauchy-Schwarz again we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2+w}{(x+y+z)^3}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{(x+y+z)^3}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{w^2+w(x+y+z)}{(x+y+z)^3}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{(x+y+z)^3}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{w^2(x+y+z+w)}{(x+y+z)^3}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{w(x+y+z+w)}{(x+y+z)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y+z+w}{x+y+z}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{w^3}{(x+y+z)^3}+2\sum_{cyc}\frac{w^2}{(x+y+z)^2}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{w}{x+y+z}=$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}+\frac{4}{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{w}{x+y+z}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{w^3}{(x+y+z)^3}+2\sum_{cyc}\frac{w^2}{(x+y+z)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{4}{3}+\frac{4}{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{w}{x+y+z}+\frac{1}{16}\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{w}{x+y+z}\right)^3+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{w}{x+y+z}\right)^2\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{4}{3}+\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{3}+\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^3+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2=\frac{112}{27}.$$